# Krippendorff's Alpha using R - Error in sort.list(y) : 'x' must be atomic for 'sort.list' Have you called 'sort' on a list?

Tags: r, alpha, irr

I'm trying to compute the inter-rater reliability between 3 raters and I have 7100 rows of data. So for example each row is like this:
5,4,3

```
> data <- read.csv("/home/xyz/Desktop/tc.csv", header=TRUE)
> library(irr)
Loading required package: lpSolve
> kripp.alpha(data, method="ordinal")
Error in sort.list(y) : 'x' must be atomic for 'sort.list'
Have you called 'sort' on a list?
```

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

it is probably a bit late, but if you provide a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example), the chances that someone may answer your question are much higher. Otherwise it is really difficult to figure out what went wrong. However I can read from your code that you have fed kripp.alpha with a dataframe (output of read.csv), which is not what the function expects. So you can probably fix the error by converting the dataframe into a matrix with the as.matrix command (The  [kripp.alpha function](https://rdrr.io/cran/irr/man/kripp.alpha.html) expects its input to be a numeric matrix with the observations in the columns and the observer/rater in the rows)

Best regards,